# How to get true Orientation/Rotation value after a Transform applied?

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

In my code, I am currently loading an Entity using the `.loadAsync(named: String)` method, then adding to my existing `AnchorEntity`.  As a test, I am then rotating my Entity 90°, and would like to determine how to then get the current angle of rotation.

The long-term intent is that I am going to allow users to rotate a model, but want to limit the rotation to a certain degree (I.E., the user can rotate the pitch of the model to 90° or -90°, but no further than that).  Without being able to know the current angle of rotation for the Entity, I am unsure what logic I could use to limit this.

```
Entity.loadAsync(named: "myModel.usdz")
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    .sink { completion in
        // ...
    } receiveValue: { [weak self] entity in

        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.objectAnchor.addChild(entity)
        scene.addAnchor(objectAnchor)
        
        let transform = Transform(pitch: .pi / 2,
                                    yaw: .zero,
                                   roll: .zero)
        
        entity.setOrientation(transform.rotation,
                                  relativeTo: nil)
        
        print(entity.orientation)

        // Sample Output: simd_quatf(real: 0.7071069, 
        //                           imag: SIMD3<Float>(0.7071067, 0.0, 0.0))
    }
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

I would have expected `entity.orientation` to give me something like `90.0` or `1.57` (`.pi / 2`), but unsure how I can get the *current* rotation of the Entity in a form that would align with expected angles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### simd_quatf

In RealityKit 2.0, when retrieving `simd_quatf` structure's values from `.orientation` and `.transform.rotation` instance properties, the default initializer brings `real` (scalar) and `imaginary` (vector) parts of a [Quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion):

```
public init(real: Float, imag: SIMD3<Float>)
```

Hamilton's quaternion expression looks like this:

[image]

In your case, the value `0.707` corresponds to a rotation angle of 45 degrees. If you set both `real` (*a*) and `imag.x` (*bi*) to `0.707`, you'll get a total rotation angle of 90 degrees for X axis.

[image]

It's easy to check:

```
let quaternion = simd_quatf(real: 0.707, imag: [0.707, 0, 0])   // 90 degrees
entity.orientation = quaternion
```

To check what "readable" model's orientation is, use regular parameters from another initializer:

```
public init(angle: Float, axis: SIMD3<Float>)

print(entity.orientation.angle)         // 1.5707964
print(entity.orientation.axis)          // SIMD3<Float>(0.99999994, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply, @Andy Jazz!  I did not realize that the rotation properties were leveraging the mathematical calculations applicable to the quaternion, and had more-so expected than the `entity.orientation.angle` output would be a per-axis angle calculation.  Would you suggest any particular documentation or reading resources to better understand how to best calculate the per-axis angle of a quaternion rotation (IE to know the angle of the pitch vs. yaw)?  Again, thank you for the reply, this was so helpful and thorough.

Comment: Hi @ZbadhabitZ, Any documentation on the subject of 4x4 matrices, Quaternions and Eulers would be helpful. ))  https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch,_yaw,_and_roll

Comment: Thank you, @Andy Jazz!  I very much appreciate your helpful and detailed answer as well as this resource.  This has been a great help and I am certain this information will help other developers interested in RealityKit and rotation, as well.